# Programmatically lock hard drive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a program that is going to periodically (on a schedule) backup/format a hard drive. During the format, I have a 2nd (identical) drive that will take it's place. What I want to do is to lock the drive to be formatted (let's say F:\) and (this part is optional ...) redirect any traffic from F:\ to the other drive (let's say G:\).

So, is there a way using C# that I can "lock" the F:\ drive so that no one can read/write it? I don't want someone to try to write to the drive just before a format is run. For my purposes right now, the key is not to be able to write to the drive, but I would prefer a total lock (read and write). I know for a file I can use `File.Open(FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)` to prevent others from accessing it. Is there something similar for drives?

If that is possible, then as a bonus, is there a way that I can redirect any traffic from F:\ to G:\? (G:\ is being replicated from F:\ in near real time, so any reads/opens should be ok to simply replace F with G in the file path, but I'm not sure if this is possible programmatically).

Comment: Have you tried writting to the drive while formatting? Doesn't `format` lock the drive by itself?

Comment: Formatting unmounts the drive, so yes. There will be a brief time between the backup and the start of the format though (as it's backed up in *near* real time). I'm looking to lock the drive so I can take the backup and then start the format without the risk that something is saved while backing up, or worse, in between the backup and the format.

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> So, is there a way using C# that I can "lock" the F:\ drive so that no one can read/write it?

Yes, though not c# so you'll need to p-invoke but use IOCTL [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL DeviceIoControl(
  (HANDLE) hDevice,            // handle to a volume
  (DWORD) FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,   // dwIoControlCode
  NULL,                        // lpInBuffer
  0,                           // nInBufferSize
  NULL,                        // lpOutBuffer
  0,                           // nOutBufferSize
  (LPDWORD) lpBytesReturned,   // number of bytes returned
  (LPOVERLAPPED) lpOverlapped  // OVERLAPPED structure
);
```

MSDN:

> Locks a volume if it is not in use. A locked volume can be accessed only through handles to the file object (*hDevice) that locks the volume. For more information, see the Remarks section
>
> ...This operation is useful for applications that need **exclusive access** **to a volume** for a **period of time** — for example, disk utility and **backup programs**

OP:

> ...is there a way that I can redirect any traffic from F:\ to G:\?

I'm not aware

Comment: It may be possible to change the letter of the F: drive, then `subst` F: to use G:

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah good idea.  I must give it a try sometime :)